# Where I can choose the unique value when I add a field in table - Navicat

Tags: navicat

In my navicat, I want to add a field, but I think its value should be unique.

But in navicat, I can not find a way or option to choose, like `Not Null` or `Character Set`.

[image]

So, where is the unique option in Navicat for a field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's available in **Indexes** tab.

[image]

Comment: does the Name, Fields, Index Type Index method will all write by me?

Comment: Name is whatever you want.
Fields is the field you want set index on.
Index Type: Unique (as you expected).
Index method: depends on your requirements.